# Modernizr and CSS - Any reason this rule isn't applied?

Tags: javascript, css, touch, modernizr

I'm using Modernizr, and I want to use a Google Maps when -no-touch is available. And use a static map when .touch is available. Like so:

```
.no-touch #map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
}

.touch #map-canvas-static {
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=63.439016,10.416856&zoom=15&format=png&sensor=false&size=1583x1583&maptype=roadmap&style=element:geometry|saturation:-71&style=feature:water|saturation:-2|color:0x768080|lightness:34&markers=63.439114,10.415564&&scale=1');
    background-position: center;
}
```

HTML Markup is as simple as this:

```
<section id="map">
    <div id="map-canvas-static"></div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</section>
```

Are there any reasons why this would not work?

Because on my desktop computer, this is working just fine. However on the iPhone I'm testing it with, it's not.

Comment: Does it work without any Modernizr specific classes?, if so it could be a problem with the way you've set up Modernizr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Modernizr.touch test only indicates if the browser supports touch
>   events, which does not necessarily reflect a touchscreen device. For
>   example, Palm Pre / WebOS (touch) phones do not support touch events
>   and thus fail this test. Additionally, Chrome (desktop) used to lie
>   about its support on this, but that has since been rectified.
>   Modernizr also tests for Multitouch Support via a media query, which
>   is how Firefox 4 exposes that for Windows 7 tablets. For more info,
>   see the Modernizr touch tests.
>
> It's recommended to set both touch *and* mouse events together, to
>   cater for hybrid devices – see the Touch And Mouse HTML5 Rocks
>   article.

http://modernizr.com/docs/#touch

In my opinion, you can use simple JavaScript to detect mobile devices, like so:

```
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      $(body).addClass('.touch')
    }
```

And then you can use your CSS code.

Comment: Looks like I was experiencing something as simple as cache problems.. I've learned to use incognito mode all the time now.

I'll look into setting touch and mouse events together. Also, your comment on modernizr.touch doesn't necessarily reflect a touchscreen device, doesn't Modernizr have those kind of checks? Such as your sample code?

Comment: Modernizr does not tell you anything about the device... only the browser.

There are devices with touchscreens running browsers which don't support Touch Events; there are devices without touchscreens running browsers which do support Touch Events.